# What percentage of a population needs a test in order to estimate prevalence of a disease? Say, COVID-19

Tags: sampling, panel-data, statistical-power, point-estimation, signal-detection

A group of us got to discussing what percentage of a population needs to be tested for COVID-19 in order to estimate the true prevalence of the disease.  It got complicated, and we ended the night (over zoom) arguing about signal detection and characteristics of the imagined test.  I'm still thinking about it...

So:

1. Assuming a perfect test, how do you plot the curve of testing reducing the confidence interval around true population infection rate?
2. Assuming an imperfect test, how do you introduce the signal detection problem of test false positives and negatives?
3. How do you model all this over time?

I'd love a textbook answer, a reference to a paper (ideally with math, not code), or a convincing argument.

Comment: For the part where you consider imperfect tests, perhaps see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455129/trying-to-estimate-disease-prevalence-from-fragmentary-test-results).

Comment: When you say "what percentage of a population" do you mean: we test people who seem ill or have had contact with ill people and publish the results (what most testing currently is). Or we test a representative sample of people and publish that (a small amount of this type testing has been done)

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/456175/35989

Comment: As with opinion polls, the sample size isn’t the main issue. The hard bit is getting a sample that is truly representative of the total population.

Comment: This is one of those cases where _defining_ the population already starts to be an issue. You've got problematic sub-populations like the homeless and illegal immigrants, which are also likely to overlap and be high-risk groups for COVID-19.

Answer (score 33):

1)  Making some assumptions about the population size (namely that it is large enough that a binomial model is appropriate), the prevalence of a disease in a population at a particular time can be obtained by <strike>sampling</strike> *simple random sampling* of people and finding who is sick.  That is a binomial random variable and the Wald confidence interval for a proportion $p$ is

$$ p \pm 1.96\dfrac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

The variance portion is bounded above by 0.5, so we can make the simplifying assumption that the width of the confidence interval is $\sim 2/\sqrt{n}$. So, the answer to this part is that the confidence interval for $p$ decreases like $1/\sqrt{n}$.  Quadruple your sample, halve your interval.  Now, this was based on using a Wald interval, which is known to be problematic when $p$ is near 0 or 1, but the spirit remains the same for other intervals.

2) You need to look at metrics like specificity and sensitivity.

**Sensitivity** is the probability that a diseased person will be identified as diseased (i.e. tests positive).  **Specificity** is the probability that a person without the disease is identified as not having the disease (i.e. tests negative).  There are lots of other metrics for diagnostic tests found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) which should answer your question.

3) I guess this is still up in the air.  There are several attempts to model the infection over time.  SIR models and their variants can make a simplifying assumption that the population is closed (i.e. S(t) + I(t) + R(t) = 1) and then I(t) can be interpreted as the prevalence.  This isn't a very good assumption IMO because clearly the population is not closed (people die from the disease).  As for modelling the diagnostic properties of a test, those are also a function of the prevalence.  From Bayes rule

$$ p(T+ \vert D+) = \dfrac{P(D+\vert T+)p(T+)}{p(D+)}$$

Here, $P(D+)$ is the prevalence of the disease, so as this changes then the sensitivity should change as well.

Comment: +1.  It may be worth emphasizing that the "sampling" to which you refer **must** be *simple random sampling,* because it's unlikely any such sample will be obtained, especially in a longitudinal or temporal study ("model this over time").

Comment: You have two different definitions of specificity, both in bold. Did you mean them that way?

Comment: @RichardHardyn Whoops.  Submit an edit and I will accept.  Currently AFK

Comment: It's probably worth defining $n$ explicitly here - I was staring at this trying to figure out why the population size mattered (for a sufficiently large population) until I realized that $n$ was probably the sample size.

Comment: $n$ is defined through the context of the use in a confidence interval.

Comment: Since usually you do not select twice the same person to be tested the underlying probability distribution should be hypergeometric. If the population is large it is approximately binomial.

Comment: @PietroC  Great point, thank you for adding that!

Comment: For us non-math geeks, can you please provide a concrete example for point 1? Meaning, assume a specific population size and sample size, show what the calculation looks like ("therefore we can say that 65.23% += 5% of the population has been infected with the disease in the past")

Comment: @Gili the calculations are outlined in my answer, and are shown in my first equation. If $x$ people out of a sample of $n$ have tested positive for the disease, then $p=x/n$.  Its simply a matter of plugging in $p$ and $n$ where relevant.  Again, the justification for the use of the binomial relies on the assumption that sample random sampling without replacement can be performed, and that the probability of drawing a sick person is not affected too much by the non-replacement.

Answer (score 13):

It has been answered by Dimitri Pananos, I will only add that in order to estimate the prevalence with pre-set precision you need an **absolute sample size** which is pretty much invariant with the population size (only when the sample is a substantial part of the target population you have a non-negligible finite population correction factor). So there is not a percentage of the population that needs to be tested: 50% of a small population may not be sufficient, 0.5% of a large population may be far enough for the same precision.

Comment: I think a key point made earlier is that sample size in and of itself is not enough. You have to have a sampling frame that allows you to generalize to the population. If you don't have that you could have a very large number of cases, random sample, and your analysis be wrong. I think this tends to get ignored in a lot of discussions of sampling and sample size (and is the really hard thing to get right).

Comment: @user5285, yes, that's true. But the point is that, even in the case of simple random sampling, asking for the percentage of the population required to sample to obtain a given precision, is wrong. The same logic applies to stratified or more complex sampling designs. Except for very small populations, what matters is not the fraction of the population you are sampling, but the number of units sampled.

Comment: @F.Tusell What you are saying is that the gain in confidence from sampling 10% of the American population instead of 1% is minimal, while the gain in confidence from increasing from 1% to 10% of a population of 100 (say, a nursing home) is enormous. Or, the other way round, the difference in confidence between testing 10,000 people in NYC vs. the entire U.S. is small (if we simplify and assume a homogeneous population to make the samples representative).

Comment: Apparently testing 1500 people in each of the 50 largest cities (a total of 75,000 tests) would provide a 98% reliable infection rate that is ± 3% of the actual infection rate. If the proportion turns out to be 10% then we become 99% confident that this is ± 2% of the actual infection rate.

Comment: @polcott, yes that matches my calculations.

Comment: @F.Tusell Since so many lives are at risk by not having this sampling it really seems to be a dereliction of duty that this sampling was not done weeks ago. There are even many experts that claim the infection rate may be 50-fold higher than reported thus making the mortality rate no greater than the seasonal flu. I wrote the Mayor of New Your about this.

Comment: @polcott, the infection rate may be quite different in a matter of days. Anyhow, I do not understand the reasoning relating the number of deaths to the number of infected people. What matters is the absolute number of lives. I find little comfort in the thought that the actual number of deaths comes from a very large pool of infected people, if that were the case.  That this is no common flu can be seen from the stress upon hospitals in countries with well developed health systems: in Spain we have been close to collapse, and the end is still far ahead.

Comment: There are many people on Facebook that are saying that none of the safety measures are are required and telling people to ignore them because covid-19 is no more dangerous then the seasonal flu. Their basis for this advice is the hypothesis that the actual infection rate is 50-fold higher than being reported, thus making the covid-19 fatality rate 0.02%. If we did stratified random sampling of 1500 New Yorkers we could refute this hypothesis and save many lives.

Comment: Another aspect of this analysis is that even if the covid-19 per infection fatality rate is only 0.02% other differences between it and the seasonal flu could still kill far more people than the seasonal flu. If everyone got infected even at the 0.02% fatality rate that would still be 6.5 million deaths, 192-fold greater than the seasonal flu.

Comment: to get 6.5e6 deaths with a fatality rate of 0.02% (1 in 5,000), you'd need a population of 6.5e6 * 5e3 = 32.4e9, almost 5 times the world's current population. I think there may be something wrong with your computation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go in a somewhat different direction and say that it depends...

- Of course any sampling is based on the notion that the sampling is truly random. Trying to account for non-randomness in the sample tremendously complicates the situation.
- This type of yes/no measurement is non-parametric. Such tests need a larger sample size than if the measurement was parametric.
- Presumably you're ignoring the problem of false positives and false negatives in the testing. False positives could be a real problem is the disease fraction is low.
- What is the actual fraction of the diseased? If only 0.1% of the population is diseased then on average one 1 in a 1000 tests would be positive. So the lower the infection rate, the larger the sample would need to be.
- How precise an estimate do you want? In other words do you want to know the infection rate +/- 20%, or to say +/- 1%. The more precise you want to know the value of the infection rate the larger the sample would need to be.

There is a type of statistical testing called Acceptance Testing which can be used. Basically the important decision is how precise do you want the measurement to be? Then you keep sampling until that level of precision is achieved. So if 50% of the population is infected then a relatively small sample is needed to get to +/- 10% error in the measurement itself (e.g 50% +/- 5%). However if only 0.5% of the population is infected then a much larger sample is needed to determine that the disease level (e.g.  0.5% +/- 0.05%).

Comment: I disagree with your fourth bullet, the prevalence of the disease has nothing to do with the sample size needed to describe estimate that prevalence. The width of the confidence interval on your estimate depends mainly on sample size. In fact, for equal sample sizes, the closer the prevalence estimate is to 0, the *narrower* the confidence interval. I suppose this might be true if you're talking about a relative sense of estimating a 0.1% prevalence vs a 0.2% prevalence, but in an absolute sense, prevalence doesn't really affect sample size needed.

Comment: @NuclearWang - If the prevalence is 50% how many random samples do you need to have a 95% confidence that you have at least one positive? If the prevalence is 0.5% how many random samples do you need to have a 95% confidence that you have at least one positive?

Comment: I don't see how "likelihood of finding at least one positive" is related to the precision of the prevalence estimate. With 100 samples, if you find 0 positives, your prevalence confidence interval is [0%, 0.5%]. If you find 50 positives, your prevalence confidence interval is [39.7%, 60.3%]. You don't need to find *any* positives to have a very good estimate of disease prevalence. In fact, the fewer you find, the better evidence you have that the prevalence is very low.

Comment: @NuclearWang - If you have 0 positives how do you tell if the disease prevalence is increasing or decreasing?

Comment: As of April 14 CDC data showed 661,712 cases in the US. The 2019 population of the US was 328.2 million giving an infection rate of 0.20%. So 100 perfectly chosen random samples would tell you little about the disease prevalence, but it would give you a reasonable estimate of males to females in the US.

Comment: Sampling 100 individuals for infection would peg the infection rate to somewhere within a half a percent. Sampling that many for sex provides a far *less* reasonable estimate, as the confidence interval is 40 times larger. The proportion of males could be anywhere from 40-60%, but we know that at least 99.5% of the population is not infected. You don't sample until you find a positive, you sample a sufficient number to get the statistical power you want, which is the confidence interval width, dependent mostly on N.

Comment: I think what's tricky here is that we're talking about low prevalence, serious events where a few tenths of a percent might matter. So, there may be a real need to have a large sample size to have a very narrow confidence interval and precise estimate. But recognize that if we needed such a precise estimate of sex ratio, we would need *an even larger sample* to do it. I guess your line of thinking boils down to low prevalence events requiring narrower confidence intervals, but if we're happy to be within 0.5% no matter what, it's easier the rarer the event is.

Comment: @NuclearWang - *We're having a violent agreement.* My point is that I want to know the value of the measurement itself to with 10% of its value. So for males are  50% +/- 5% of the population. The infection rate is 0.2% +/- 0.02%. My points have been (1) that not knowing what the infection rate is you can't have a predefined  a sample size to get a error of +/- 10% of the value. (2) For the data that I gave on sex vs infection rate you'd need a much larger sample for the infection determination.

Comment: There are probably two models 1) Low population density 2) High population density.  Looking at curves from China it was symmetrical while curves from NYC are coming down slowly and have a plateau.  I suspect that there is some natural immunity that is affecting the curves.   Assumptions from John Hopkins is No Natural immunity and Every body will get the disease.  NYC is showing 20% positive for antibodies, but I think this is low because the test is for COVO-19 and not other strains that may give immunity.